# Concert tabular data into Objects through LINQ

Tags: linq

```
       StudentId    Name  AddResss
        1            A      ABC
        1            A      XYZ
```

How Can i convert above result into List of following Objects

```
     Class Result {
      int StudentId {get;set;}
      List<String> Address {get;set;}
      }
```

Basically need to group by on studentId

Comment: What does the source data structure look like? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

```
studentList.GroupBy(x => x.StudentId)
           .Select(x => new Result 
                        { 
                            StudentId = x.Key,
                            Address = x.Select(y => y.AddResss).ToList()
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results =
    from row in table
    group row.Address by new { row.StudentId, row.Name } into g
    select new Result { StudentId = g.Key.StudentId, Addresses = g.ToList() };
```

Comment: You should explain your answer.